# When converting a csv_reader object to a list, the ouput is a list of object lists followed by an empty list. Why does this happen?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying convert a csv_reader object to a list using the list() function but when I print it out, the result is a list of lists (each object list followed by an empty list). Why does this happen?

Code to replicate:

```
with open('data.csv') as file:
  reader = csv.reader(file)

print(list(reader))
```

result:

```
[['trs_id', 'prd_id', 'prc'], [], ['1000', '1', '15'], [], ['1001', '2', '25'], []]
```

Comment: Could be a lot of things. What OS are you using? What line endings does your CSV have?

Comment: Add a sample of the _CSV_ file, to the question.

Comment: Try adding the `newline=‘’` property to `open(…)`. Also, your file could have blank rows.

Comment: Does this [help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents)

Comment: Thank you, @ZachYoung, for your solution. You were right; my file contained blank rows. I resolved the issue by adding `newline= ''` to the write block of the CSV file.